# How to decrypt in PHP a string encrypted with 3DES in C#?

Tags: c#, php, encryption

I'm using the following code to decode a string in a C# program of mine but I also need to be able to decrypt the same string server side with PHP. Is there an equivalent in PHP of the following c# code?

```
public static string DecryptString(string Message, string Passphrase)
    {
        byte[] Results;
        System.Text.UTF8Encoding UTF8 = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();

        // Step 1. We hash the passphrase using MD5
        // We use the MD5 hash generator as the result is a 128 bit byte array
        // which is a valid length for the TripleDES encoder we use below

        MD5CryptoServiceProvider HashProvider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] TDESKey = HashProvider.ComputeHash(UTF8.GetBytes(Passphrase));

        // Step 2. Create a new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider object
        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider TDESAlgorithm = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();

        // Step 3. Setup the decoder
        TDESAlgorithm.Key = TDESKey;
        TDESAlgorithm.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        TDESAlgorithm.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

        // Step 4. Convert the input string to a byte[]
        byte[] DataToDecrypt = Convert.FromBase64String(Message);

        // Step 5. Attempt to decrypt the string
        try
        {
            ICryptoTransform Decryptor = TDESAlgorithm.CreateDecryptor();
            Results = Decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(DataToDecrypt, 0, DataToDecrypt.Length);
        }
        finally
        {
            // Clear the TripleDes and Hashprovider services of any sensitive information
            TDESAlgorithm.Clear();
            HashProvider.Clear();
        }

        // Step 6. Return the decrypted string in UTF8 format
        return UTF8.GetString(Results);

    }
```

Comment: Look at the `mcrypt` module (http://php.net/mcrypt).

Comment: Just in case anyone want need it. http://stackoverflow.com/a/29045516/1693635

Answer (score 3):

To get the MD5 hash in PHP, use [`$key = md5($passphrase, true)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php). The second parameter gives you the raw output instead of its hex encoding.

To encrypt/decrypt using Triple DES, you can use the [`mcrypt`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php) module. In its simplest form:

```
$ciphertext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_3DES, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
```

Considerations:

- Triple DES uses 192-bit keys, but you have a 128-bit key. PHP pads the key with nulls, but .NET won't allow keys like this. Instead, it appends the first 8 bytes onto the end.
- .NET uses PCKS7 padding, PHP uses zero-padding.

To get around these incompatibilities, you'll have to make some modifications to standard code. This was lifted from a [post on php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php#68368):

```
function encryptNET3DES($key, $vector, $text){
    $td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_3DES, '', MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, '');

    // Complete the key
    $key_add = 24 - strlen($key);
    $key .= substr($key, 0, $key_add);

    // Padding the text
    $text_add = strlen($text)%8;
    for ($i=$text_add; $i<8; $i++){
        $text .= chr(8-$text_add);
    }

    mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $vector);
    $encrypt64 = mcrypt_generic($td, $text);
    mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
    mcrypt_module_close($td);

     // Return the encrypt text in 64 bits code
    return $encrypt64;
}
```

Finally, to encode/decode base64 strings, use [`base64_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) and [`base64_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php)

Answer (score 0):

i want to decrypt code from `.net` into `php`. 
my `.net` encryption and decryption methods are as follow:

```
public class EncryptDecrypt
{
    private byte[] TDES_Key = { 0x01, 0x04, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x09, 0x07, 0x08, 0x01, 0x09, 0x07, 0x08, 0x01, 0x01, 0x02, 0x04 };
    private byte[] tdesIV;
    public string Encrypt(string textToEncrypt,string KeyVI)
    {
        tdesIV = GetLegalKey(KeyVI);
        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        tdes.Key = TDES_Key;
        tdes.IV = tdesIV;
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textToEncrypt); 
        return Convert.ToBase64String(tdes.CreateEncryptor().TransformFinalBlock(buffer, 0, buffer.Length));/// 
    }
```