# Decrypting in PHP a string encoded 3DES with C#

Tags: php, encryption, 3des, tripledes

I have to decrypt in PHP a string encoded with this C# class (it's [here](http://www.deltasblog.co.uk/code-snippets/basic-encryptiondecryption-c/))

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

public static class Encryption
{
   public static string Encrypt(string input, string key)
   {
      byte[] inputArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
      TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tripleDES = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
      tripleDES.Key = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
      tripleDES.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
      tripleDES.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
      ICryptoTransform cTransform = tripleDES.CreateEncryptor();
      byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(inputArray, 0, inputArray.Length);
      tripleDES.Clear();
      return Convert.ToBase64String(resultArray, 0, resultArray.Length);
   }

   public static string Decrypt(string input, string key)
   {
      byte[] inputArray = Convert.FromBase64String(input);
      TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tripleDES = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
      tripleDES.Key = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
      tripleDES.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
      tripleDES.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
      ICryptoTransform cTransform = tripleDES.CreateDecryptor();
      byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(inputArray, 0, inputArray.Length);
      tripleDES.Clear();
      return UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultArray);
   }
}
```

I've tried different examples found around on the web, but nothing seems to work. I think that the first problems comes with the $iv parameter in php mcrypt_generic_init and then another problem comes with padding that is missing in php functions.
Can you please help me to convert the c# Decrypt function above in PHP?
Thank you.

Comment: If you want to try a solution that doesn't require `mcrypt`, and would make your code more portable to instances that don't have it, you can try [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/). This will use the mcrypt functions if they are available, and an internal implementation if not.

Comment: Is this useful: http://sanity-free.com/131/triple_des_between_php_and_csharp.html

Comment: The **IV** should not matter since the C# code is using `CipherMode.ECB` (which is bad IMO).

Comment: @poupou yes, IV does not matter and ECB should only be used for plain text that cannot be distinquished from random data (e.g. other, securely generated secret keys)

Comment: Pons, don't set the IV, it should not be present in ECB mode and a bad implementation might XOR the first plain text block with the given IV anyway. You had better switch to CBC and use an IV though, it might be more compatible with between implementations as well (as ECB is unsafe in most descriptions I've seen on stackoverflow).

Answer (score 2):

Because the IV does not matter in ECB mode, we can ignore it.  However, mcrypt isn't very lenient.  We still need to provide *an* IV, even if it's fake.

```
// We'll be encrypting this data
    $key = 'password';
    $data = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs.';
    $encrypted = null;
    
// 3des in ECB mode
    $m = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_3DES, null, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, null);
// Our IV will be enough NUL bytes to satisfy mcrypt.
    $fake_iv = str_repeat(chr(0), mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($m));
    mcrypt_generic_init($m, $key, $fake_iv);
    $encrypted = mcrypt_generic($m, $data);
// "s/6HOXpVyMyFdSPYUgIgneMRY0o3Kubkwc++hSg9kC4Sw0TWsNTqzrhXY3z4PH9w"
    echo base64_encode($encrypted), "\n";
    unset($m);

// And now, in reverse!
    $n = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_3DES, null, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, null);
// Another fake IV
    $fake_iv = str_repeat(chr(0), mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($n));
    mcrypt_generic_init($n, $key, $fake_iv);
    $original = mdecrypt_generic($n, $encrypted);
// string(48) "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs."
    var_dump($original);
```

Again, you'll only want to do this if you stick with ECB mode.  ECB mode can be pretty awful.  You might want to review [the Wikipedia article on block cipher modes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation) for more information.

The only thing not handled here is the padding.  mcrypt doesn't let you pick the padding method, and does something different depending on the cipher.  Generally, it does not add any padding at all.

If your padding method of choice uses NUL bytes, you'll need to pre-pad the data yourself to ensure interoperability.  You can use [`mcrypt_get_block_size`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-get-block-size.php) and [`str_pad`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) with the `STR_PAD_RIGHT` option to do this.

Likewise, you might need to trim NUL bytes off of the right after you decrypt.  The second parameter to [`trim`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) will help.

Comment: Charles did the right thing there setting the IV to bytes valued 00h and using the appropriate function to determine the number of bytes. In CBC mode the plain text is XOR'ed with the IV vector, and XOR'ing with 00h valued bytes won't change the plain text. So even if the IV would be used by the underlying code, feeding it zero's won't hurt.

Answer (score 2):

Even I tried today code for both PHP and C#

```
<?php
$key64 = "YOUR_KEY";
$iv64 = "YOUR_IV";


$keybytes = base64_decode($key64);
$ivbytes = base64_decode($iv64);

$text = ("4111111111111111");

// Padding the text
$padding = strlen($text)%8;
for($i=$padding; $i<8; $i++){
   $text .= chr(8-$padding);
}

$decryptRaw = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_3DES, $keybytes, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $ivbytes);
$encoded = base64_encode($decryptRaw);

print "$encoded<br/>";
$encryptedString64 = $encoded;
$decryptbytes = base64_decode($encryptedString64);

$decryptRaw = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_3DES, $keybytes, $decryptbytes, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $ivbytes);
$decryptString=trim($decryptRaw,"\x00..\x1F");
print "$decryptString<br/>";

?>
```

C#

```
private string Decrypt(string encryptedValue)
{
    SymmetricAlgorithm tripleDESKey = SymmetricAlgorithm.Create("TripleDES") ;
    tripleDESKey.Key = Convert.FromBase64String("YOUR_KEY");
    tripleDESKey.IV = Convert.FromBase64String("YOUR_IV") ;

    MemoryStream encryptedStream = new MemoryStream();
    encryptedStream.Write(Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedValue), 0,
    Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedValue).Length);
    encryptedStream.Position = 0;
    CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(encryptedStream,
    tripleDESKey.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
    MemoryStream decryptedStream = new MemoryStream();

    byte[] buf = new byte[2049];
    int bytesRead = 0;
    bytesRead = cs.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
    while ((bytesRead > 0))
    {
        decryptedStream.Write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
        bytesRead = cs.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
    }
    return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(decryptedStream.ToArray());
}
private string Encrypt(string encrypt)
{
    SymmetricAlgorithm sa = SymmetricAlgorithm.Create("TripleDES") ;
    sa.Key = Convert.FromBase64String("YOUR_KEY");
    sa.IV = Convert.FromBase64String("YOUR_IV") ;
    byte[] inputByteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(encrypt);
    MemoryStream mS = new MemoryStream();
    ICryptoTransform trans = sa.CreateEncryptor();
    byte[] buf = new byte[2049];
    CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(mS, trans, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
    cs.Write(inputByteArray, 0, inputByteArray.Length);
    cs.FlushFinalBlock();
    return Convert.ToBase64String(mS.ToArray());
}
```